# Opening the correct version of EB GUIDE which fits to the model

Tags: batch-file

We have to work with different versions of EB GUIDE (migration to newer not always allowed/possible); depending on the model format, we have to use the corresponding EB GUIDE version (always running on Windows).
We would like to start the correct version of EB GUIDE when starting the ebguide model file.

EB GUIDE files have the file extension `.ebguide`. It turns out the first line always starts with something like (this could be used to identify the correct version of EB GUIDE):

```
EBGUIDE 6.8.0.190612124148;
```

I managed to start EB GUIDE using a batch file (i.e. link the file extension to my batch file). How can I write the batch file so that it always starts the correct version of EB GUIDE? The content of my batch file:

```
rem How to determine and run the correct version?
"C:\Program Files\Elektrobit\EB GUIDE 6.8\studio\Studio.exe" %1
```

The question is: How to start the correct version of Studio.exe depending on the first line of the .ebguide file?

Comment: Are they pure text files? Get the first line with `set /p "version="<"filename.ebguide"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number should be part of the metadata of the application. You can read it with `wmic`:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
REM set "file=C:\Program Files\Elektrobit\EB GUIDE 6.8\studio\Studio.exe"
set "file=C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic datafile where name^="%file:\=\\%" get Version /format:list') do set version=%%I
echo %file% has version %version%
```

`Wmic datafile` works only with full paths, it expects the backslashes to be doubled and due to the `for` loop the `=` has to be escaped (the first one. The second one is protected by surrounding quotes)

**EDIT** It seems I completely misunderstood your question.

Assuming, the `*.ebguide` files are plain text (I have to guess here) (ANSI and UTF8 will work too, but Unicode won't; May even work with binaries if you are lucky), get the first line with a `set /p` and extract the major version with a `for /f` loop. Now you are able to build the path to the correct `studio.exe`,

```
@echo off
setlocal    
set /p "version="<"%~1"
echo ---%version%---
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=. " %%a in ("%version%") do set "version=%%a.%%b"
echo ---%version%---
set "program=C:\Program Files\Elektrobit\EB GUIDE %version%\studio\Studio.exe" 
echo ---%program%---
if not exist "%program%" echo No fitting Studio.exe & goto :eof
echo ---executing %program%---
"%program%" "%~1"
```

all `echo ---...` lines are just for debugging.